# easy way to record and visualize a page connections in an existing website

Tags: web-scraping, web

is there a simple way to create a program that will crawl a website and record every pages then make a flowchart from the pages connection? Or is there an existing one right now?

The website is using umbraco and I want to record the existing pages and where it connects starting from the homepage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.